# How to copy char array of a structure into another char array of a structure?

Tags: c++, arrays, structure

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct stud
{
    char name[10];
    int id;
};

int input(stud a[], int size)
{
    for(int i=1; i<=size; i++)
    {
        cout<<"name = ";
        cin>>a[i].name;
        cout<<"id = ";
        cin>>a[i].id;
    }
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
int output(stud a[], int size)
{
    for(int i=1; i<=size; i++)
    {
        cout<<"name = "<<a[i].name<<" ";
        cout<<"id = "<<a[i].id<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}

int copy(stud a[], stud x[], int size)
{

    for(int i=1; i<=size; i++)
    {
        x[i].name=a[i].name; 
        x[i].id=a[i].id;
    }
    output(x,size);
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{

    struct stud s[3], x[3];
    input(s,3);
    output(s,3);
    copy(s,x,3);
    return 0;
}
```

In this program the statement in function copy `x[i].name =a[i].name;` is not copying contents from 1 structure object to another. I have tried to put this statement in for loop `for(int j=1;j<=10;j++) x[i].name[j] =a[i].name[j];` but still not working.
please suggest what should be changed or some alternatives for this.
i'll be very thankful to you for this.

regards,
umar

Comment: name is of type array. So when you just mention name of array it is of type pointer. So structureVariable.name is of type char* so assignment you are doing is wrong you should do strcpy to copy one string to other.

Comment: If this is true char array and not a string, you will need a way to know the buffer size and should use `memcpy()`.  From your example though, it appears you mean strings and not char arrays.

Comment: There is a standard function for this: `std::copy`

Comment: My C preference is showing again... :)

Comment: You tagged the question as `c++`, so I'd like to suggest that it might be more convenient for you to use `std::string` instead of mere arrays, which will actually allow you to do the copying the way you wanted, by simply assigning. :)

Comment: The loop would have worked if you had started at index 0, like all arrays in C++ do.  Every single one of your loops contains an off-by-one error and accesses outside the array it is supposed to use.

Comment: Off-Topic: Using `std::cin` with a `built-in array` with specific length, can cause to `Buffer Overflow`; Don't use it in products!

Comment: Side note: Because valid array indexes start at 0 and run to size-1, `for(int i=1; i<=size; i++)` Starts one late and ends one past the end of the array.  Use `for(int i=0; i<size; i++)` instead.

Comment: Also note, you already have a student id, refactor the name into a map<id, name> and you dont need to copy the names at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either using a loop to copy each character in the `name` field or using the`strcpy` function from `<cstring>` header works.

```cpp
int copy(stud a[], stud x[], int size) {
    for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
        // for(unsigned j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        //     x[i].name[j] = a[i].name[j];
        // }
        strcpy(x[i].name, a[i].name);
        x[i].id = a[i].id;
    }
    output(x, size);
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

But since you tagged this as `c++`, consider using `std::string` instead of a char array, unless you have a particular reason for using a char array. In that case `x[i].name = a[i].name` would have worked just fine and you could also use the standard `algorithm` library for copy. Also, using `std::array` instead of a raw C array for you "array of structures" might be a better option (does not degenerate into a pointer like a regular C array does).

Answer (score 1):

Evrey single one of your loops is wrong, because in C++ arrays start at zero. So not

```
for(int i=1; i<=size; i++)
```

instead

```
for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
```

You cannot copy arrays by writing `a = b;`. Since your arrays are really strings there's a built in function `strcpy` to copy strings.

```
strcpy(x[i].name, a[i].name);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `=` to copy struct, the char array inside that struct will be copied. You don't need to do anything more.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
typedef struct{
    char name[10];
} type_t;

int main() {
    type_t a = {"hihi"};
    
    type_t b;
    b = a;
    
    a.name[0] = 'a';
    
    cout<<a.name<<endl;
    cout<<b.name<<endl;
    

    return 0;
}
```

output:
aihi
hihi

ideone: https://ideone.com/Zk5YFd